# redirect dynamic bad url to new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Trying to redirect this example format which now produces a 404

archive/topic/t-59411_Nastase_RHIC_produces_black_holes.html

to this format which works:

archive/index.php/t-59411.html

I can only find examples of what to do if they were query strings.  The number 59411 is the dynamic ID

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/archive/topic/t-(\d+)_(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)\.html$ http://your.domain/archive/index.php/t-$1.html
```